# Implementing dark mode in React Native sensibly

Tags: react-native, ios13, ios-darkmode, android-darkmode

I'm trying to add dark mode support to my React Native app. I will have a flag in a mobx store `mode` which will be `light` or `dark` as appropriate.

In order to tie this into an existing app, I wanted to, if possible, keep the existing style definitions and only override when needed (rather than rewrite everything to a light and a dark theme).

I came up with a function like the following to return the appropriate styles based on the current mode:

```
function getStyle(style) {
  let ret = [styles[style]];
  if (
    styles.hasOwnProperty(Store.mode) &&
    styles[Store.mode][style] !== "undefined"
  ) {
    ret.push(styles[Store.mode][style]);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The view would be rendered as such:

```
...
<View style={getStyle("container")}>
  <Text style={getStyle("text")}>Some text</Text>
</View>
...
```

The styles:

```
const styles = {
  dark: {
    container: {
      backgroundColor: "#000"
    },
    text: {
      color: "#fff"
    }
  },
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#000"
  }
};
```

Now this works, but I'm not sure if it's coming at some performance cost I'm unaware of right now (the use of the function, using a style object instead of `StyleSheet.create`...), or if there's a much simpler way I can't see for the trees. I'd rather not do a ternary inline on every element either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going a slightly different way, in that I'd add extra styles depending on the current mode, e.g.

```
<View style={[styles.container, theme[Store.mode].container]}>
  <Text style={[styles.text, theme[Store.mode].text]}>Some text</Text>
</View>
```

And then using the theme var to override

```
const theme = {
  light: {},
  dark: {
    container: {
      backgroundColor: "#000"
    },
    text: {
      color: "#fff"
    }
  }
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#000"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) api in ReactJS. It gives a good out of the box solution for maintaining global data around the component tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.createContext()` and `react-native-paper`

This module makes it simple to change the background with just a button. I made a simple example for you.

I made an [example link.](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/react.createcontext-example)

[image: gif i made]

Comment: @besthorse If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' sign and arrow for my answer?